# Getting the name of class from which a method is being called for logging in Java

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j for logging purpose in Java. When I use log.info(some message),it logs the api from which the function is being called along with the message,which is what it does.
But my case scenario here is different which I am explaining through code snippets.

```
ClassA{
 void log(String message){
   log.info(message);
   }
}

ClassB{
classA obj = new classA();
obj.log("hello");
}
```

In this case while logging log4j will log classA in the log file. But I want it to show classB instead of A. Is it possible achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

You can use one more parameter which contains the name of the class from where you called.

e.g.

```
ClassA{
void log(String message, String className){
// Edit the log4j details
log.info(message);
}
}

ClassB{
classA obj = new classA();
obj.log("hello", this.getClass().getSimpleName()); //here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, wrapping a `Logger` object inside a custom class like that seems pretty unnecessary, and ... as you are seeing ... it introduces this problem that you wouldn't normally have.

However, it may be possible to make it work.  Internally, the log4j formatting code is creating an `Exception` object to capture the current stack trace, and then trawling that to identify the calling class, method and source file / line.  What you could do is to modify the behavior (ideally by overriding things in a custom class) so that it uses the next stack frame up the stack from the one it would normally use.

Unfortunately, relevant log4j code is all heavily abstracted, and rather hard to follow.  It would take a few hours for me to figure out the best way to make the necessary changes, and I don't have the inclination to do that.  (As I stated at the outset, what you have done is a bad idea ...)

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is while creating the constructor of log4j pass the name of the class that you want to be in log and rest you can do usually.

Answer (score 1):

what I did is defined

```
 private static MyLogger logger = MyLogger.getLogger(GetPlanOptionsForPackage.class)
```

and then

```
logger.error("input cannot be null");
```

this solved my use case